# Page redirection not working for Android device

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am working on Captive Portal. So when user join internet login page will come. once user entered credential it will show success page.So success page was loading before.My work was on success page load i need to redirect our url. So i hide all designs and body on load i wrote script for redirection. It works in ios and windows but not working in Android device.It is just loading page for 2 seconds then disappearing automatically.I tried through iframe but it did not work.

```
<body onload="redirect()">
<div>
<iframe name="iFrameName" src="" frameBorder="0" >
</iframe>
</div>
<script>
function redirect() 
{
//   if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) 
//     window.open("http://xxxx.xxx/",'_system')    
//   else
//     window.location.replace("http://xxxx.xxx/");
var site = "http://xxxx.xxx/";
document.getElementsByName('iFrameName')[0].src = site;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Commented code i tried fast, but it did not work.Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is disabled in a WebView by default. You need to turn it on:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad lvchenko.I tried this in my script tag inside my html webpage, it throws error. Not supporting. Can you please tell how to inject this code in script section ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you give internet permission into android mainfest file like this way..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Try this code..

```
   mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.bluehost.com/track/businessplan/");
```

Comment: Thanks @Android Team for reply. But can you please tell how to inject this code in script section in my html web page ?